# Dynamic Namespaces SocketIO - Django - NodeJS - Redis

Tags: node.js, django, redis, socket.io, namespaces

I am using NodeJS as a second backend to my Django project and I want the namespaces to be dynamic like

```
nsp = io.of('/:namespace')
```

In which the namespace comes from the Django template.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Almost everything, but mainly the code that I posted.